# How to connect two elements in a SVG tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jsplumb

I have a central SVG tag in which multiple elements such as rect, circle etc are being drawn dynamically. How can I connect those two.

I tried using jsPlumb but [this](https://blog.jsplumbtoolkit.com/posts/connecting-svg-shapes.html) page at jsPlumb blog states that

> THE PROBLEM
> You cannot connect two rect elements (or any SVG shapes) directly. This is because the shapes inside an SVG element do not have the same positioning information as all other DOM elements. So now consider you have this markup:

I have been researching since two days to look for a way but all libraries either connect two DIVs together or two SVG tags together. Is there a way to connect SVG ELEMENTS together?

Answer (score -1):

I think a solution is described in your [link](https://blog.jsplumbtoolkit.com/posts/connecting-svg-shapes.html) (in "THE SOLUTION" section). You need to define the way to compute the offset for each shape, and then override some jsPlumb methods (getOffset and getSize).

Then, you'll be able to use JSplumb to connect the rectangles.

Comment: I read that. I am gonna have a lot of different types of shapes, even custom shapes so defining each shape's coordinates or offsets wouldn't be very efficient

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to figure out the offset of a custom shape, either. You simply get the coordinates of the four furthest points on the shape in each direction - topmost, rightmost, bottommost, leftmost (in `{x,y}` format). Then use the width `rightmost.x-leftmost.x` and height `bottommost.y-topmost.y` to calculate your offsets, as you'd use the width and height of a rectangle to calculate its offset.

Comment: You may want to look at using an SVG library that offers a `getBBox()` (get bounding box) function, or else write one on your own. The bounding box should be a rectangle with the four coordinates `[[leftmost.x, topmost.y], [rightmost.x, topmost.y], [rightmost.x, bottommost.y], [leftmost.x, bottommost.y]]`.

The `getBBox()` implementation you use needs to be generic enough to to return the bounding box for any shape you will need to find the offset for, in which case you can do away with the per-shape calculators and just use each shape's bounding box to calculate your offset.